# placing stock order during overnight hours

Tags: stocks

Say I want to have a sell order for stock executed when the premarket hours begin (usually 7 AM, I believe), but I can't be at my computer at 7 AM.  Is there a way to schedule the order the night before (either during or after extended hours) and have it automatically executed at 7 AM?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your broker and their website

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can submit orders 24/7. Just make sure to submit it after the market is closed in the evening (or it would be executed right away).
You can choose a limit or market order; but a market order is dangerous, as trading on the new day might start at a very different price.

Answer (score 1):

Some brokers require that you request permission for pre and after market hours trading.  Assuming that you have it, you can place any type of limit order that your broker offers, any time that you like. Your order will only be "automatically executed at 7 AM"  market price has reached your limit price.

Comment: Knew that, forgot that.  Thanks for catching it.